# ASp.Net GridView Updating using a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, gridview, datagridview

I've read tons of sites on this. There are many "Examples" if you call some code with no explanation of how it was generated (design view vs typed) an example or just want to use simple select and update statements.

I have a Gridview. I am populating it using code from a stored proc. Now I want to edit the data.  I have nothing set in the properties of the Gridview through design view (datasource, columns, etc.)  My question is, how can I set this to allow editing and use a SP to send it back to the database?

Do I have to now manually create columns with code since I chose to not set properties in the design view?

Is it better to set the properties in design view and go that route? I started that way, but had problems when it came to updating with a SP.

I guess the whole do it in the designer vs do it in code thing has me confused.

I started adding RowEdit, RowCommand, etc. to the html and c#, but still don't see the EDIT/CANCEL on the webpage when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use the ObjectDataSource. It gives you maximum freedom of what way of storing the data you use - you delegate the select, update and delete to an external class where you just write your code which uses ado, linq, hibernate, a webservice or just anything.

Coding your views directly against fixed database structure would hurt you sooner or later.

Comment: It is, in a sense that you can't easily change its structure or move to another database engine.

Comment: The chances of completely changing databases in a project is small. You will still have to update your object. Something is going to have to be updated to change databases. I am trying to do this as simple as possible since I am new to Web apps.

Comment: We are not only talking about good practices but also try to focus on your actual question. Based on my 11 years of experience with asp.net, I've shown you a right direction which easily solves your issue. Of course, you can argue but I feel this leaves you with unsolved problem. I really don't think an easier way exists there, in your very specific context.

Comment: Even if I use a Objectdatasource, the question goes back to my original question. Do I set that up in the gridview through the GUI or with code? Setting up through the GUI does not seem like a good best practice. If you do it through the code, it seems like a pain specifying all the fields by type (bound, command edit,etc). In non-web development, we never used the wizards or setup things through the GUI. We always used code.

Comment: Years ago I've published a tiny tutorial on that for my students, I hope you'll find it useful http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~wzychla/ra2829/example3.zip and http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~wzychla/ra2829/example3a.zip

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I am using the Rowupdatign event to write my data. It updates it, but gives an error after because I don't have an Updatecommand set.  Not sure how to get around that. I shouldn't need one because I am doing the update myself manually.

Comment: There are two possible approaches. First, you can update in RowUpdating and point to a dummy UpdateMethod. Second, you can just gather data and pass it to UpdateMethod. I prefer the second as it makes responsibilities clear - the view gathers data, the business object behind the objectdatasource does the actual update. Note that no matter what you do, the UpdateCommand must be set but it can point to a method that possibly does nothing.